# spring integration Kafka when and why does producer connection refreshes?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-kafka

I am using spring integration kafka outbound channel adapter and below is the configuration.

```
<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter sync="true" 
    kafka-template="kafkaTemplate" id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter" 
    topic="learning-topic" channel="KafkaAdapterChan" 
    send-failure-channel="FailureChan">
</int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="kafkaTemplate" class="org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="xyz:9092" />
                    ... <!-- more producer properties -->
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I see the log **ProducerConfig values:** with all the default values during start up of application. However, I see this logs randomly even when application is not restarted. I believe Kafka producer is refreshing/resetting the connection. I see the first kafka publish takes more time(around 3-5 seconds) for a 300 partition kafka cluster and no logs available in INFO or DEBUG mode(apart from kafka metadata refresh). Can someone advise when does the Kafka producer tries to refresh the connection(and logs the config values)? Is there any kafka producer config to enable/disable the auto connection refresh? Or something to verify that is causing this connection refresh?

Comment: The delay you see on a first interaction is about fetching metadata for the topic. The auto-reconnect stuff might be something internal to Apache Kafka client by itself.

Comment: The `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` does have a `maxAge` property, but it is zero by default, so Spring will never close a producer (unless you are using transactions and some error occurs within a transaction. or a send fails with an `OutOfOrderSequenceException`).

Comment: @GaryRussell: thanks Gary, but there are no timeouts or exceptions, still the connection gets refreshes without any server restarts. And it is not happening in dev(with 1 broker) not sure what else is causing the connection refresh.

Comment: I have no idea either; I can only tell you that Spring will not refresh the producer (except under the circumstances I cited).

Comment: @GaryRussell, I am trying to enable trace mode and see if I can find any error. Also, producer connection is happening on first publish. Could you please suggest the best way to connect immediately once the JVM is up.

Comment: By default, the `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` creates a single shared producer. You could try creating the producer from the factory and calling some utility method like `partitionsFor(...)` on that producer to force some interaction with the broker.